# How do I change the value from Regedit of my Ram and Rom memory?

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-registry, disk-space

For example, I know that entering Regedit you can change the processor name, put the name of a processor that does not even exist, but I would like to know how to change the ram memory and storage values from Regedit and if there is any way or scrip to run every time the PC is turned on.

Comment: From the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask): you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. What is the actual problem then? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: Yeah, this is incredibly dodgy - like something a dishonest person might to to try sell a computer for more then its worth.  (Which is also why somemone might create a new account to ask this question)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the likely purposes for this are dishonest.